# ServiceStack idle timeout

Tags: servicestack

My biggest problem with my ServiceStack apps so far is the service timing out after the user is idle for a long period of time.  I have read all the authentication notes but I'm fairly new to web authentication so I'm not always sure which features will help.

The current app I'm testing is actually a Winforms app that serves as an offline client to a web app, but can occasionally log onto the service when connected to the internet. When logging in with this app, what is the best was to keep the (singleton) serviceClient logged on until the program closes?

thank you.

Comment: How do you host the Service? Perhaps you run into some issues with IIS apppool sleep?

Comment: It sounds like a user authentication token/cookie expiring. This can be avoided by using a different auth scheme, such as passing credentials in the headers (encrypted/hashed, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas Enkler was correct - the IIS Application Pool timeout was shutting down the ServiceStack service. Thanks for the tip!